# discord py in Visual Studio Code not detecting extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.py

I installed discord.py with the voice and without in the visual studio code terminal because in my cmd it doesn't detect pip like a command (I'm on windows). I've tried too in the python terminal but it doesnt detetect pip like a command. 
Please help.

Comment: Are you asking for help to install the library, or getting pip to work? _in my cmd it doesn't detect pip like a command (I'm on windows). I've tried too in the python terminal but it doesnt detetect pip like a command._ Have you done any research? I know for a fact those issues have been covered before both on SO and other sites.

Comment: You need to add python to your path.

Comment: I want to install the library

Answer (score 0):

Pip is installed, it's just not installed as a command, and that's [on purpose](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/). What you want to do is create a virtual environment and then install into there by activating the environment and then using `python -m pip`.